# Cucumber 4 JVM parallel run with extent reporter

Tags: maven, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, extentreports

I am  trying to use cucumber 4 to run parallel test execution. I am also trying to use extent reporter with this. Maven test build should also run the test code. I am also trying to keep implementation independent of my test code.
I got everything else to work except extent reporter.
My maven dependecies:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sitture</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-extentreport</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>3.13.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Here is my runner

```
     @Test
public void test() throws Throwable {
    Main.main(new String[]{
            "--threads", "2",
            "-p", "html:target/cucumber/",
            "-p", "pretty:target/cucumber/cucumber-pretty.txt",
            "-p", "json:target/cucumber/cucumber.json",
            "-p", "junit:target/cucumber/cucumber.xml",
            "-p", "usage:target/cucumber/cucumber-usage.json",
            "-p", "com.sitture.ExtentFormatter:target/output/extent-report/index.html", 
            "-g", "bdd.steps", "src/test/resources"});
}
```

Now its throwing error:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface cucumber.api.TestCase, but class was expected
at com.sitture.ExtentFormatter.handleStartOfFeature(ExtentFormatter.java:160)
at com.sitture.ExtentFormatter.handleTestCaseStarted(ExtentFormatter.java:110)
at com.sitture.ExtentFormatter.access$100(ExtentFormatter.java:36)
at com.sitture.ExtentFormatter$2.receive(ExtentFormatter.java:63)
at com.sitture.ExtentFormatter$2.receive(ExtentFormatter.java:60)
at cucumber.runner.AbstractEventPublisher.send(AbstractEventPublisher.java:45)
at cucumber.runner.AbstractEventPublisher.sendAll(AbstractEventPublisher.java:52)
at cucumber.runner.CanonicalOrderEventPublisher.handle(CanonicalOrderEventPublisher.java:18)
at cucumber.runtime.formatter.Plugins$1.receive(Plugins.java:55)
at cucumber.runner.AbstractEventPublisher.send(AbstractEventPublisher.java:38)
at cucumber.runner.AbstractEventBus.send(AbstractEventBus.java:9)
at cucumber.runner.TimeServiceEventBus.send(TimeServiceEventBus.java:3)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:98)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:26)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:8)
at bdd.util.TestRunnerParallel.test(TestRunnerParallel.java:11)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

For details you can visit my test code https://github.com/hossainelahi7/Cucumber-JVM4-extentreporter

Comment: Welcome to the site. Remember that  links go stale and these Questions and Answers are supposed to be helpful for others in the future. Please provide all relevant info in the post.

Comment: Do not think this supports cucumber version 4. It supports only till cucumber 2.3.1. https://github.com/sitture/cucumber-jvm-extentreport/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Have a look at this - http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/4/java/cucumber4.html

Comment: As @Grasshopper mentioned, use the above link which points to the cucumber4-adapter since cucumber4 natively supports parallel tests.  You don't need to use the JVM-parallel plugin in this case.